# Error gives after sudo apt-get upgrade

Tags: command-line, apt, upgrade, updates

It gives the error

`dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.`

I tired to `sudo dpkg --configure -a` after that and
it gets stuck at `Setting up install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ...`

and does'nt proceed please help.

Comment: Could you post the last few lines of the output of `dpkg -D2000 --configure -a`

Comment: Hi i tried everything but i cant get any line after sudo dpkg --configure -a .I think i have to fix the problem with manually.